# Using hibernate with annotations, i want a one-many relationship to be sorted

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Using hibernate with annotations, i want a one-many relationship to be sorted by the 'created' field on the 'many' table.

So far i've got this, which always ends up in a random order:

```
// The notes 
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="task_id")
Set<TaskNote> notes;
public Set<TaskNote> getNotes() {return notes;}
public void setNotes(Set<TaskNote> notes) {this.notes = notes;}
```

Comment: I think i need to change the Set to a List, and maybe use @OrderBy("created"), but it never seems to work for me.

Comment: Oh wait, that works fine now. Well, if someone's got a better solution, i'm still interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since neither answer gave you the full solution :

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="task_id")
@OrderBy("created")
List<TaskNote> notes;
public List<TaskNote> getNotes() {return notes;}
public void setNotes(List<TaskNote> notes) {this.notes = notes;}
```

`Set` is unordered, so use `List` instead, and you need the `@OrderBy` annotation too.

Comment: My answer was a full solution.  You don't need to specify @OrderBy to achieve order, you can specify it in how you retrieve data.  I'd argue that this is more flexible, since @OrderBy is not dynamic.

Comment: ok fair enough, i guess the wording of OP's question seems to me to indicate they want to use annotations to always order in a specific way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a List instead of a Set.  A List preserves order, a Set doesn't.  Using a List, the order of the elements will match whatever you specify for your ORDER BY in HQL or using Criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, you can either
`@OrderBy("created")` which will do what you would expect in SQL.

You can also `@Sort` which allows you to specify an arbitrary comparator implementation, if you want to sort in memory for some reason.

Edit: unpredictable iteration order is an implementation detail of HashSet, it's not part of the contract of the Set interface.  Hibernate will happily use LinkedHashSet when you use XML mapping and specify ordering on a set.  I assumed it does the same when you use the annotation, apologies if that was incorrect.