# Can Hibernate automatically manage the order of child collections?

Tags: java, hibernate

Given a `Parent` class which has many `Children`, can Hibernate automatically manage the order of said children? From reading documentation and searching, it seems that the `@OrderColumn` annotation may enable this, but I've not found any examples of how to do it. The closest thing I've found is [JPA 2.0 @OrderColumn annotation in Hibernate 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/jpa-2-0-ordercolumn-annotation-in-hibernate-3-5), which looks a bit discouraging, given that it looks just like what I want to do.

Here is a rough sketch of what I'm trying to do, minus the annotations, since I'm not sure what they would be:

```
class Parent {
  // I probably need some sort of @OrderColumn annotation here, right?
  private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>;
}

class Child {
  private Parent parent;
  private int order;
}

class SomeBusinessLogic {
  public static void createFamily() {
    Parent dad = new Parent("Tom");
    List<Children> children = dad.getChildren();
    children.add(new Child("Alice");
    children.add(new Child("Bob");
    children.add(new Child("Carl");
    session.save(dad);
  }

  public static void addChild(Parent parent) {  // assuming Tom is passed in
    List<Children> children = parent.getChildren();
    children.add(1, new Child("Zelda");
    session.save(parent);
    // now, the order should be: Alice, Zelda, Bob, Carl
  }
}
```

If someone can give me enough details to make this toy example work (or tell me that it will not work), I would be most appreciative.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [2902553](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2902553/851811). Take a look at `@OrderBy`

Comment: Xavi, I'm more interested in the automatic updating of the order column when I save the `Parent`. Adding an `@OrderColumn` annotation to `Parent` orders the children correctly when I get a `Parent` from the database, but I can't figure out how to persist a reordering. `@OrderBy` only handles the getting side of the problem, and thus won't suffice for me.

Comment: Do you want to insert the collection in a given order?

Comment: @Udo: Yes, I want the new child records to be inserted in the order of the children list.

Answer (score 1):

In order to store children in its order you should map it with `@IndexedColumn` annotation it will create indexed column on your child objects table.